# Is a React Native Application able to run on a windows server?

Tags: windows, react-native, windows-server

I did some searching around, but the only thing I could find, was that React Native was launched on windows.

However, does this also include a windows server? Or just a normal windows PC?

Sorry if this question is stupid, but thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is a view library. It is used to build the View Layer in traditional MVC Applications.

React Native uses the core React library along with components to create native applications on a target Operating System.

React Native doesn't target Windows as far as I know and so wouldn't target Windows Server as well.

However, Electron apps would be fine on Windows and Windows Server.